# How to fit a Michaelis-Menten model with a random effect using the nlmer function in R?

Tags: r, lme4

We would like to fit a Michaelis-Menten function to a dataset where "CTIR" is the response variable (and corresponds to feeding rate), "FL" is the independent variable (corresponding to food level) and "Tank" is a random effect with two levels, 1 and 2. The code we have so far is adapted from (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101154/how-to-fit-a-michaelis-menten-function-with-a-random-effect-using-the-nlme-packa)).

The model should allow us to obtain a p-value for the slope and intercept, as well as an R2 and an AIC value. The data for the model can be found here: https://dalu-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/ek717816_dal_ca/EaDPOacdHvdOhAU-lOjNuQUByIgWKepuYBkd2WthxPXc7g?e=9JyWkQ

```
# Load required library
library(lme4)

#Load data
tirsfl <- read.csv("TIR.FL.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",") 
names(tirsfl)

#Michaelis-Menten model (TIR vs. FL)
michaelis_menten_model <- function(FL, maxTIR, FoodK) #Write the MM function
  {maxTIR * (FL / (FL + FoodK))}

# Fit the model using nlmer
fit <- nlmer(TIR ~ michaelis_menten_model(FL, maxTIR, FoodK) + (1 | Tank), #Fit the model
             data = tirsfl,
             start = c(maxTIR = max(tirsfl$TIR), FoodK = median(tirsfl$FL)))
summary(fit)
```

We are getting the following error code after running the nlmer:

Error in eval(form[[2]]) : object 'TIR' not found

How can it be fixed?

Comment: Kindly check this document https://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/slides/2009-07-01-Lausanne/8NLMMD.pdf as well as file:///Users/mdumar/Desktop/v80i03.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I tried something here, is this working

```
tirsfl <- read_excel("Book5.xlsx")
names(tirsfl)
[1] "FL"   "Tank" "TIR" 

fit <- nls(TIR ~ Vm*FL / (K+FL), data = tirsfl, start = list(Vm = max(tirsfl$TIR), K = median(tirsfl$FL)))
summary(fit)

Formula: TIR ~ Vm * FL/(K + FL)

Parameters:
    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
Vm 1.289e+00  8.573e-02  15.039   <2e-16 ***
K  2.499e+03  1.489e+03   1.678   0.0984 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3852 on 61 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 6 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 5.304e-06
```

So, in case your code, I edited Michaelis-Menten model (as per original equation, or algorithm) and believe to fit your dataset using the nls function. The start argument provides initial parameter values for the optimization process. The summary of the model will give you information about the estimated parameters, R-squared, and other relevant statistics.

```
# Michaelis-Menten model function
michaelis_menten_model <- function(FL, Vm, K) {
  Vm * FL / (K + FL)
}

# Fit the model using nls
fit <- nls(TIR ~ michaelis_menten_model(FL, Vm, K),
           data = tirsfl,
           start = list(Vm = max(tirsfl$TIR, na.rm = TRUE), K = median(tirsfl$FL, na.rm = TRUE))) #, na.rm = TRUE is exceptional, if u want u can exclude in your code, it is just for handling empty or NA value 

# Summary of the model
summary(fit)

Formula: TIR ~ michaelis_menten_model(FL, Vm, K)

Parameters:
    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
Vm 1.289e+00  8.573e-02  15.039   <2e-16 ***
K  2.499e+03  1.489e+03   1.678   0.0984 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3852 on 61 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 6 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 5.304e-06
```

some references are here
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167947306004592?via%3Dihub

u can also use maxTIR inplace of Vm and FoodK in place of K, just a matter of lette, I just followed original equation, so keep things concise and clear, which help me in correcting code

Random effects:

```
michaelis_menten_model <- function(FL, Vm, K) {
  Vm * FL / (K + FL)
}

# Fit the model using nlme
fit <- nlme(TIR ~ michaelis_menten_model(FL, Vm, K),
            fixed = Vm + K ~ 1,
            random = Vm ~ 1 | Tank,
            data = tirsfl,
            start = c(Vm = max(tirsfl$TIR), K = median(tirsfl$FL)))  # Set starting values based on your expectations

# Summary of the model
summary(fit)
    Nonlinear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
  Model: TIR ~ michaelis_menten_model(FL, Vm, K) 
  Data: tirsfl 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  64.49737 73.06991 -28.24868

Random effects:
 Formula: Vm ~ 1 | Tank
                Vm  Residual
StdDev: 0.03813024 0.3774968

Fixed effects:  Vm + K ~ 1 
       Value Std.Error DF   t-value p-value
Vm    1.2902    0.0893 60 14.444882  0.0000
K  2472.7841 1467.9035 60  1.684569  0.0973
 Correlation: 
  Vm   
K 0.736

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-1.97035191 -0.75386255 -0.05710474  0.88745509  2.10844581 

Number of Observations: 63
Number of Groups: 2
```

Comment: It works, but nls does not incorporate the random effect "Tank", which is crucial!

Comment: can u try this 
michaelis_menten_model <- function(FL, Vm, K) {
  Vm * FL / (K + FL)
}
#
fit <- nlme(TIR ~ michaelis_menten_model(FL, Vm, K),
            data = tirsfl,
            fixed = Vm + K ~ 1,
            random = Vm + K ~ 1 | Tank,
            start = c(Vm = 100, K = 10))  # Adjust starting values as needed

# Summary of the model
summary(fit)

Comment: If you need to incorporate the random effect "Tank," you may want to consider using the nlme package for non-linear mixed-effects modeling.

Comment: try this also 
# Fit the model separately for each level of Tank
fit_tank1 <- nls(TIR ~ michaelis_menten_model(FL, Vm, K), 
                 data = subset(tirsfl, Tank == 1),
                 start = list(Vm = max(tirsfl$TIR), K = median(tirsfl$FL)))
########
fit_tank2 <- nls(TIR ~ michaelis_menten_model(FL, Vm, K), 
                 data = subset(tirsfl, Tank == 2),
                 start = list(Vm = max(tirsfl$TIR), K = median(tirsfl$FL)))

# Combine the results
summary(fit_tank1)
summary(fit_tank2)

Comment: is this fine 
# Michaelis-Menten model (TIR vs. FL)
michaelis_menten_model <- function(FL, maxTIR, FoodK) {
  maxTIR * (FL / (FL + FoodK))
}

# Fit the model using nlsList
fit <- nlsList(TIR ~ michaelis_menten_model(FL, maxTIR, FoodK) | Tank, data = tirsfl,
               start = list(maxTIR = max(tirsfl$TIR), FoodK = median(tirsfl$FL)))
summary(fit)

Comment: Hi, can u try this and please let me know 
my_model <- function(FL, Vm, K) {
  Vm * FL / (K + FL)
}

# Fit the model using nlme
fit <- nlme(TIR ~ my_model(FL, Vm, K),
            fixed = Vm + K ~ 1,
            random = Vm ~ 1 | Tank,
            data = tirsfl,
            start = c(Vm = max(tirsfl$TIR), K = median(tirsfl$FL)))
summary(fit)

Comment: or this one ##
my_model <- function(FL, Vm, K) {
  Vm * FL / (K + FL)
}

# Fit the model using nlme
fit <- nlme(TIR ~ my_model(FL, Vm, K),
            fixed = Vm + K ~ 1,
            random = Vm ~ 1 | Tank,
            data = tirsfl,
            start = c(Vm = 10, K = 1))  # Set starting values based on your expectations